# Retrying combinations of 91 elements until a criteria is met

Tags: java

Im developing a software where I need to creat a lineup of 9 players with a set of criteria, and Im starting to wonder if this is an impossible problem or if theres not enought computing power to solve it in useful time.
If anyone could help or guide me with this I would thank them immenseley.
A simple pseudo-code or logic guidance would be perfect.

Here's the criteria:
91 players from 6 different teams, each have a cost.
5 Positions: 4 of them are pairs, the other is a solo position.
Paired positions cant have 2 players of the same original team.
The lineup cant have mora than 3 players from the same team.
The final cost of the lineup can't be higher than 60000$

I know Ill be getting hate for extremely repeated and unnecessary code, but Im too paranoid..

```
int totalSal = 0;
    while (numPG != 2 && numSG != 2 && numC != 1 && numPF != 2 && numSF != 2 && totalSal < 60000) {//enquanto o salario total < 60000
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfPlayers.getNumPlayers(); i++) {//para cada jogador
            if (team1 == 3) {
                t1blocked = true;
            } else if (team2 == 3) {
                t2blocked = true;
            } else if (team3 == 3) {
                t3blocked = true;
            } else if (team4 == 3) {
                t4blocked = true;
            } else if (team5 == 3) {
                t5blocked = true;
            } else if (team6 == 3) {
                t6blocked = true;
            }
            System.out.println("Seeing player number " + i);
            if (numPG < 2 && totalSal <= 20000) {
                Player selected = listOfPlayers.getPlayerAt(i);
                if (selected.getPos().contains("PG") && selected.getSalary() <= 15000 && selected.getUsed() == false) {
                    if (selected.getTeam().contains("POR") && !t1blocked) {
                        team1++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numPG++;
                    } else if (selected.getTeam().contains("OKC") && !t2blocked) {
                        team2++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numPG++;
                    } else if (selected.getTeam().contains("WAS") && !t3blocked) {
                        team3++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numPG++;
                    } else if (selected.getTeam().contains("PHO") && !t4blocked) {
                        team4++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numPG++;
                    } else if (selected.getTeam().contains("LAL") && !t5blocked) {
                        team5++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numPG++;
                    } else if (selected.getTeam().contains("DAL") && !t6blocked) {
                        team6++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numPG++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (team1 == 3) {
                t1blocked = true;
            } else if (team2 == 3) {
                t2blocked = true;
            } else if (team3 == 3) {
                t3blocked = true;
            } else if (team4 == 3) {
                t4blocked = true;
            } else if (team5 == 3) {
                t5blocked = true;
            } else if (team6 == 3) {
                t6blocked = true;
            }
            if (numSG < 2 && totalSal <= 30000) {
                Player selected = listOfPlayers.getPlayerAt(i);
                if (selected.getPos().contains("SG") && selected.getSalary() <= 15000 && selected.getUsed() == false) {
                    if (selected.getTeam().contains("POR") && !t1blocked) {
                        team1++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numSG++;
                    } else if (selected.getTeam().contains("OKC") && !t2blocked) {
                        team2++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numSG++;
                    } else if (selected.getTeam().contains("WAS") && !t3blocked) {
                        team3++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numSG++;
                    } else if (selected.getTeam().contains("PHO") && !t4blocked) {
                        team4++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numSG++;
                    } else if (selected.getTeam().contains("LAL") && !t5blocked) {
                        team5++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numSG++;
                    } else if (selected.getTeam().contains("DAL") && !t6blocked) {
                        team6++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numSG++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (team1 == 3) {
                t1blocked = true;
            } else if (team2 == 3) {
                t2blocked = true;
            } else if (team3 == 3) {
                t3blocked = true;
            } else if (team4 == 3) {
                t4blocked = true;
            } else if (team5 == 3) {
                t5blocked = true;
            } else if (team6 == 3) {
                t6blocked = true;
            }
            if (numSF < 2 && totalSal <= 40000) {
                Player selected = listOfPlayers.getPlayerAt(i);
                if (selected.getPos().contains("SF") && selected.getSalary() <= 15000 && selected.getUsed() == false) {
                    if (selected.getTeam().contains("POR") && !t1blocked) {
                        team1++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numSF++;
                    } else if (selected.getTeam().contains("OKC") && !t2blocked) {
                        team2++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numSF++;
                    } else if (selected.getTeam().contains("WAS") && !t3blocked) {
                        team3++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numSF++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numSF++;
                    } else if (selected.getTeam().contains("PHO") && !t4blocked) {
                        team4++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numSF++;
                    } else if (selected.getTeam().contains("LAL") && !t5blocked) {
                        team5++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numSF++;
                    } else if (selected.getTeam().contains("DAL") && !t6blocked) {
                        team6++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numSF++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (team1 == 3) {
                t1blocked = true;
            } else if (team2 == 3) {
                t2blocked = true;
            } else if (team3 == 3) {
                t3blocked = true;
            } else if (team4 == 3) {
                t4blocked = true;
            } else if (team5 == 3) {
                t5blocked = true;
            } else if (team6 == 3) {
                t6blocked = true;
            }
            if (numPF < 2 && totalSal <= 50000) {
                Player selected = listOfPlayers.getPlayerAt(i);
                if (selected.getPos().contains("PF") && selected.getSalary() <= 15000 && selected.getUsed() == false) {
                    if (selected.getTeam().contains("POR") && !t1blocked) {
                        team1++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numPF++;
                    } else if (selected.getTeam().contains("OKC") && !t2blocked) {
                        team2++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numPF++;
                    } else if (selected.getTeam().contains("WAS") && !t3blocked) {
                        team3++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numPF++;
                    } else if (selected.getTeam().contains("PHO") && !t4blocked) {
                        team4++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numPF++;
                    } else if (selected.getTeam().contains("LAL") && !t5blocked) {
                        team5++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numPF++;
                    } else if (selected.getTeam().contains("DAL") && !t6blocked) {
                        team6++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numPF++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (team1 == 3) {
                t1blocked = true;
            } else if (team2 == 3) {
                t2blocked = true;
            } else if (team3 == 3) {
                t3blocked = true;
            } else if (team4 == 3) {
                t4blocked = true;
            } else if (team5 == 3) {
                t5blocked = true;
            } else if (team6 == 3) {
                t6blocked = true;
            }
            if (numC < 1 && totalSal <= 60000) {
                Player selected = listOfPlayers.getPlayerAt(i);
                if (selected.getPos().contains("C") && selected.getSalary() <= 15000 && selected.getUsed() == false) {
                    if (selected.getTeam().contains("POR") && !t1blocked) {
                        team1++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numC++;
                    } else if (selected.getTeam().contains("OKC") && !t2blocked) {
                        team2++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numC++;
                    } else if (selected.getTeam().contains("WAS") && !t3blocked) {
                        team3++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numC++;
                    } else if (selected.getTeam().contains("PHO") && !t4blocked) {
                        team4++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numC++;
                    } else if (selected.getTeam().contains("LAL") && !t5blocked) {
                        team5++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numC++;
                    } else if (selected.getTeam().contains("DAL") && !t6blocked) {
                        team6++;
                        totalSal += selected.getSalary();
                        System.out.println("Selected the player:" + selected);
                        System.out.println("Added player. Total salary = $" + totalSal + "\n");
                        numC++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (numRestarts == 10){
                break;
            }
            if (numPG < 2 && numSG < 2 && numC < 1 && numPF < 2 && numSF < 2 && (totalSal > 60000) || totalSal < 59000) {
                System.err.println("Restarting");
                numRestarts++;
                restart();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of PG: " + numPG);
    System.out.println("Number of PF: " + numPF);
    System.out.println("Number of SF: " + numSF);
    System.out.println("Number of SG: " + numSG);
    System.out.println("Number of C: " + numC);
    System.out.println("Members of POR: " + team1);
    System.out.println("Members of OKC: " + team2);
    System.out.println("Members of WAS: " + team3);
    System.out.println("Members of PHO: " + team4);
    System.out.println("Members of LAL: " + team5);
    System.out.println("Members of DAL: " + team6);
    System.out.println("Total Salary of lineup: $" + totalSal);
}                                              
public void restart() {
    team1 = 0;
    team2 = 0;
    team3 = 0;
    team4 = 0;
    team5 = 0;
    team6 = 0;
    numPG = 0;
    numPF = 0;
    numSF = 0;
    numSG = 0;
    numC = 0;
    t1blocked = false;
    t2blocked = false;
    t3blocked = false;
    t4blocked = false;
    t5blocked = false;
    t6blocked = false;
}
private int numRestarts = 0;
private int numC = 0;
private int numPF = 0;
private int numSF = 0;
private int numSG = 0;
private int numPG = 0;
private int numEntry = 0;
private int team1 = 0; //POR
private int team2 = 0; //OKC
private int team3 = 0; //WAS
private int team4 = 0; //PHO
private int team5 = 0; //LAL
private int team6 = 0; //DAL
private boolean t1blocked = false;
private boolean t2blocked = false;
private boolean t3blocked = false;
private boolean t4blocked = false;
private boolean t5blocked = false;
private boolean t6blocked = false;
```

Comment: First of all, there is a lot of duplicated code here, especially with all that `System.out.println()` stuff. You should consider using some methods (like a `printMessage()` method) to avoid unnecessary code duplication.

Comment: I know, will rework all of those "souts", i only used them to see the stages without going into hours long of debugging :\

Comment: Well, when the post contains 344 lines of code and you are asking for help, you may want to fix that first to help with readability so others can help you out.

Comment: I can do that, but i was initially going to post the question without code, because my problem isn't in the code, but i'ts actually on my lack of knowledge on how to make a cycle for combinations.
There are 91c9 possible combinations, therefore the computer should be able to go throught all of them in a minute or so :\ I just don't know the logic behind the process. Thanks for the help by the way! :)